# Converting label to href

Tags: jquery

I have some html that looks like this:

```
<div class="generated">
<p><label for="id_group">Group</label> <select name="group" id=" id_group" tabindex="1">
<option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="1">12S</option>
<option value="2">13S</option>
<option value="3">22SOI</option>
</select></p>
</div>
```

I want to make the label 'Group' to be a href. How can I do that with jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean `a` element?

Comment: I don't understand.  You want to create an anchor tag with an href value of the for attribute in the label tag?

Comment: Why not just do <p><a href=...><label for="id_group">Group</label></a>...

Comment: Yes. I want the text 'Group' to be a clickable link.

Comment: And what would you want the `href` to be, for that link? Where should it take the user, once clicked?

Comment: @Nigel Thorne: I don't have control of the html that's generated (it's generated by a django form). So I want to modify it with jQuery.

Comment: @David Thomas: To a URL that I can easily generate.

Comment: Generate personally, or programatically? How is jQuery supposed to know your intent?

Comment: Clcking on a label correctly associated with its form element will already give focus to this form element. A link that spans the whole label should confuse the user :/

Comment: @DavidThomas: I am going to generate it programatically. Assume it's contained in a var called href.

Comment: @FelipeAls: Clicking on the label will bring the user to page in another tab that will give them detailed info about the choices available in the drop down.

Comment: I'd add this link right after the input then, with a text like "Help" or "More information". If not enough space, an (?) image of an icon with the same text alternative (Help or More info) also in a link would also be OK. Label already have a precise role in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var html = $('label[for="id_group"]').html();
$('label[for="id_group"]').html('<a href="my_link.html">'+html+'</a>');
```

NOTE: This will not replace the `label` with a `a`, but it'll insert the link inside the `label` element (so you can still keep your form's `label-input` relations).

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. But I simplified it a bit like this:


$('label[for="id_group"]').wrapInner('<a href="my_link.html"></a>')

Answer (score 1):

For this particular question:

```
$('label').replaceWith(
    function(i,r) {
        return '<a href="http://example.com/">' + r + '</a>';
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tUnQX/).