# Display URL's in labels as hyperlink

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a label in my asp.Net website which is used to display dynamic date depending on what is contained in the database.

Sometimes its Text and sometimes is a URL.

How can i make the the label display URL contents as a url?

For example if the content is: i have plaaced the link below . http://www.ucs.cam.ac.uk.

I want to display the text as text and the url as a link.

Thanks

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665571/converting-label-to-href on how to convert label to anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to parse any URLs into a link:

```
private string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string text)
{
    string regex = @"((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~_-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])";
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(regex, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return r.Replace(text, "<a href=\"$1\" title=\"Open in a new window or tab\" target=\"&#95;blank\">$1</a>").Replace("href=\"www", "href=\"http://www");
}
```

This code has the added advantage of being able to handle multiple URLs within a body of text and will pick up & convert URLs from just `www`. And if there are no URLs it'll just return the original text.

Comment: thanks,  do i just need to copy and pass your solution in my code or i need to do something else?

Comment: just copy and paste it in and pipe your data through it. I don't know how you're doing that so at a guess: `MyLabel.Text = ConvertUrlsToLinks(myText);`

Comment: Thanks, the label is contained in a listview

Comment: Won't matter you can use it anywhere. Don't forget to mark your answer please ;)